# Local and global variables inside a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, variables

I am learning JavaScript global and local variables, but I am confused on this particular function.

```
var text = "top";
function print() {
    return (text);
}
print();
// Returns 'top'
```

I understands why it returns top. `var text` is a global variable. `print()` function has access to it and returns `text`, thus returning `'top'`.

```
var text = "top";
function print() {
    return (text);
    var text = "bottom";
}
print();
// Returns undefined
```

I have a basic knowledge of global and local variables (or so I thought). I know that the function `print` has access to its own local plus global variables.

I don't understand why this returns `undefined`. To my understanding, the line `return text;` retrieves global variable `text`, which it has access to (as shown on the first code block). After returning `text = 'top'`, it also declares its own local variable with the same name but different value, `'bottom'`. The local variable `bottom`, to my knowledge, ought to sit there because it wasn't called earlier.

Why didn't it show `top` (or even shows `bottom`), but instead shows `undefined`?

Comment: No. In the second case, it returns the local variable text, which is *declared* inside the function. (That's what makes it local.) But at the point the return is executed, the variable has not been assigned a value yet.

Comment: Look up "variable hoisting" in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript [hoists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Scoping_and_hoisting) your variable declaration such that your code is functionally the following:

```
var text = "top";
function print() {
    var text;
    return (text);
    // Unreachable code below
    text = "bottom";
}
print();
// Returns undefined
```

Since `text`, as declared in your function, is not yet defined when you hit `return(text)`, and `text="bottom"` is unreachable, `print()` returns `undefined`.

See *[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)* for more. This question relates to case 7.

Answer (score 2):

This is to do with [variable hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

The code in your second example is executed in this order:

1. Declare global variable `text`
2. Set value of global variable `text` to "top"
3. Declare function `print`
4. Call function `print`
5. Declare local variable `text` (due to hoisting)
6. Return value of local variable `text` (`undefined` at this point)
7. Set value of local variable `text` to "bottom"

It is executed as if it were written like this:

```
var text = "top";
function print() {
    var text;
    return (text);
    text = "bottom";
}
print();
```

As you can see, the value of `text` is returned before actually being defined, and therefore it is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to [hoisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Scoping_and_hoisting).

> Hoisting teaches that variable and function declarations are physically moved to the top of your code.

You can get samples and explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

Answer (score -1):

Your assignment,

```
var text = "bottom";
```

comes after a return function, so it is not proper. It is an unreachable statement.

```js
var text = "top";
function print() {
    return (text);
    //var text = "bottom";
    // The above assignment comes after a return function,
    // so it is not proper. It is unreachable statement.
}
alert(print());
// Returns undefined
```

Comment: To reassign the the value "bottom" to text, it has to come before the return statement so that it can be reachable.