# How to pause a progress bar on click?

Tags: javascript

so I have set up a basic audio player with a progress bar.

So far I have a play button that makes the bar start and move, but I want to stop that progress when "Pause" is clicked, and resume when "Play" is pressed again. What would be the function for this?

My JS knowledge is pretty basic so I found this on W3schools

```js
function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 100);
    function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        width++; 
        elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
    }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
    width: 1%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Play</button> 
<button>Pause</button>
```

Comment: You've already got the code that stops the increment in your code; on pause click, `clearInterval(id)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are searching for `clearInterval()`. To keep the progress bars state, make sure to also have the width defined globally. If you define the width in the function, it'll always return back to 1.

```js
var interval;
var width = 1;

function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
 
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(frame, 100);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      width = 1;
      clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}

function pause() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Play</button>
<button onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
```

Comment: `clearInterval(id);` But you changed `id` to `interval`

Comment: you can see `var interval` is declared globally

Comment: `"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined` That's what I'm referring to. I saw global declaration afterwards.

Comment: @TimLewis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005685/local-and-global-variables-inside-javascript-function

Comment: I'm not talking about global variable declaration! You still have `clearInterval(id);` in your code, but you change `var id = setInterval(...)` to `interval = setInterval(...)`. I'll edit your code so you can see what I'm referring to. It needs to be `clearInterval(interval);`

Comment: @TimLewis Sorry. I missed it.

Comment: The working is fine but I want to progress show be smooth that will makes it more better as it is. So which property of css will work here I have used transition but it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body> 
    <div class="main_div">
    </div>
    <div class="child_main_div">
    </div>
    <button class="continue_button">Start</button>
</body>



let continue_button = document.querySelector('.continue_button');
let child_main_div = document.querySelector('.child_main_div')
let styles = window.getComputedStyle(child_main_div)


let width = 2;
let set_interval_var;
let flag_status = true;

function set_interval(func){
    set_interval_var = setInterval(func,50);
    function func(){
        if(width == 60){
            clearInterval(set_interval_var)
            continue_button.innerHTML = "Start"
            flag_status = true;
        }else{
            width++;
            child_main_div.style.width = width + '%';
        }
    }
 }


function set_interval_stop(){
    clearInterval(set_interval_var);
}


continue_button.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if(flag_status == true){
        flag_status = false;
        set_interval("mytimer")
        continue_button.innerHTML = "Pause"
        if(width == 60){
            width = 2;   
        }
    }else{
        flag_status = true;
        set_interval_stop()
        continue_button.innerHTML = "Start"
    }  
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).